# Find $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1-a^x\right)^\frac 1{x}\quad (0<a<1)$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Somebody asked
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-a^x\right)^\frac 1{x} \quad (0<a<1)$$
which is $1$. But the original question was missing the part $x\to\infty$, so I misinterpreted it as $x\to0^+$

> $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(1-a^x\right)^\frac 1{x} \quad (0<a<1)$$

which I couldn't yet figure out how to solve it. Wolfram says it's zero. Can somebody help? (without L'hopital if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

$$\left(1-a^x\right)^{1/x}=e^{\frac1x\log(1-a^x)}$$

and now:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac1x\log(1-a^x)=-\infty\implies \lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(1-a^x\right)^{1/x}=0$$

Observe that when $\;x<0,\,0<a<1\;$ , then $\;a^x>1\;$ so $\;\log(1-a^x)\;$ isn't defined as a *real function*

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Take $\log$ and use L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't there be some way to to without L'hopital? They are high school students.

Answer (score 0):

When $x\rightarrow 0^+$ then $a^x\rightarrow 1^-$, thus $1-a^x\rightarrow 0^+$ and (when $0<x<1$) then $(1-a^x)^{1/x}\leq 1-a^x\rightarrow 0$. No need to use special tools.

[No longer needed: When $x\rightarrow 0^-$ there is no limit. We have $1-a^x\rightarrow 0^-$. If we want to stay real suppose $1/x=-n$ a negative integer. But then $(1-a^{1/n})^{-n} \rightarrow \pm \infty$ depending on $n$ being diverging along even or odd integers.]

Comment: Thanks, but $1/x \rightarrow \infty$ so it becomes $0^\infty$..

Comment: "thus $1 - a^x \to 0^+$ and $(1-a^x)^{1/x} \to 0$" is not correct because $0^\infty$ is an indeterminate form.

Comment: In fact the argument of this answer is correct imo, but perhaps it'd need a little more explanation. if $\;1-a^x>0\;$ is small (and it is when $\;x\to0^+$), then since $\;\frac1x\to+\infty\;$ we have a very small positive number raised to a very high power, so that *indeed* tends to zero.